# Can I set the slider height to the height of an image in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to set my slider height to be the same as the height of the image. In this Image you can see the slider is the correct height that I want based on the height of the container using `GeometryReader`.

[image: Full screen slider]

When I have 8 of these in a row, the images get smaller (which is what I want) but the slider stays the same height.

[image: Multiple sliders]

How do I set the height of the slider to be the height of the image?

```
struct FaderView: View {
    @State var sliderValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            // Fader Background
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Image("FaderBackground")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height)
                        
                
                // Fader Slider
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Slider(
                            value: $sliderValue,
                            in: 0...127,
                            step: 1.0
                        )
                        .frame(width: geo.size.height * 0.84)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90.0), anchor: .center)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
struct MixerView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
            FaderView()
                
        }
        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake you're making is using the global coordinate space instead of the local one. Geometry Reader takes as much space as possible so the height it's reading in your code is the whole available space height, not the image view height.

If you want the correct height you could use this View extension which originally is a part of the Pure SwiftUI library.

```
public extension View {
 func geometryReader(
    _ geoCallback: @escaping (GeometryProxy) -> ()
 ) -> some View {
    geometryReader(id: 1, geoCallback)
 }

 func geometryReader<T: Hashable>(
    id: T,
    _ geoCallback: @escaping (GeometryProxy) -> ()
 ) -> some View {
    overlay(
      GeometryReader { (geo: GeometryProxy) in
        Color.clear.onAppear {
            geoCallback(geo)
        }
        .id(id)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

and implement the Fader view like this:

```
struct FaderView: View {
 @State var sliderValue: CGFloat = 0
 @State var imageHeight: CGFloat = 0

 var body: some View {
     Image("FaderBackground")
         .resizable()
         .scaledToFit()
         .cornerRadius(10)
         .geometryReader { proxy in
             imageHeight = proxy.frame(in: .local).height
         }
         .overlay {
             Slider(
                 value: $sliderValue,
                 in: 0...127,
                 step: 1.0
             )
             .frame(width: imageHeight * 0.84)
             .rotationEffect(
                 .degrees(-90.0),
                 anchor: .center
             )
         }
 }
}
```

Of course you don't have to use the extension I presented, but I find this solution clean and simplest to understand.